# 20-pin LVDS (DF14-20P) to USB/HDMI for post-processing?

Tags: video, hdmi, lvds

I am looking to convert a 20-pin LVDS (DF14-20P) signal from a thermal imager to another format (i.e. HDMI) so that I can do post-processing on a Raspberry Pi, OAK-Som, or similar.

Everything I can find that converts LVDS to HDMI seems to be 30- or 40-pin LVDS to HDMI.

So I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to convert 20-pin LVDS to HDMI?  Or does anyone have other suggestions on how to convert the LVDS to something more post-processing friendly?

Comment: Do you mean pins as in pins of a connector, wires of data/clock, or lanes of data/clock?

Comment: Here's the pin out for my connector: https://imgur.com/a/fVRnibU if that helps.  It's an 10bit signal with 8 bits of video data and 1 bit for field/line sync.  I also have info on clocks and signal profiles if that is useful